# Converting Numpy text array to tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

i have 2 a numpy nd arrays of shape (2000,) where each element is a list containing words as items. Thus each list is a sentence. The other nd array are just the binary labels.
I want to convert this to tensorflow data Dataset where each item is a sentence with a label.
I tried:

```
 tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dataset, labels))
```

but i get :

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).
```

How could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error usually occurs when each list in your array has a different number of elements (words). Try using a `ragged` representation:

```
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.ragged.constant(dataset), labels))
```

Comment: This did the trick, Gracias